# Weird behaviour by node.removeChild(child)

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a very basic layout of tables and checkboxes. I have eight textboxes and eight rows in a table. I just tried to add row on checkbox checking and remove on unchecking.

So, I am using two functions for the same.

```
function show(input){
    var tbody = document.getElementById("tbody");
    if(document.contains(document.getElementById("tr"+input)))
    {
         hide('tr'+input);
    }
    if(!document.contains(document.getElementById("tr"+input)))
    {
         tbody.appendChild(getRow(input));
    }
}

function hide(input){
    if(document.contains(document.getElementById(input)))
    {
        var child = document.getElementById(input);
        child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
        child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
    }
}
```

In the hide function, if I use only one removeChild statement, it does not work. On using two, an error is reported in the console but it works perfectly.

If anyone knows the reason, please tell me because it is not ethical to leave an error with the code.

Edit #1: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saxenageek/2vxa8/3/)

Comment: Can you provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Your code looks alright but helping you w/o a fiddle would be very time consuming for anyone.

Comment: Hey guys, please check jsFiddle link added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is this function:

```
function show(input) {
    var tbody = document.getElementById("tbody");
    if (document.contains(document.getElementById("tr" + input))) {
        hide('tr' + input);
    }
    if (!document.contains(document.getElementById("tr" + input))) {
        tbody.appendChild(getRow(input));
    }
}
```

First, you check if the node is present and, if so, hide it. Next, you *always* check if the node is *not* present and, if so, you add it. When the node was just hidden, the second check will be `true` (because you just deleted the node) and the node is added back again.

So rewrite to this:

```
function show(input) {
    var tbody = document.getElementById("tbody");
    if (document.contains(document.getElementById("tr" + input))) {
        hide('tr' + input);
    } else if (!document.contains(document.getElementById("tr" + input))) {
        tbody.appendChild(getRow(input));
    }
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2vxa8/13/)

Comment: great ... understand my fault

Answer (score 2):

Seems there is a problem with immediate repaint of the element, here is a dirty way that worked for me

```
 var child = document.getElementById(input);
 setTimeout(function(){
      child.parentNode.deleteRow(child.rowIndex - 1);    
 }, 1);
```

And it's safe to use table specific methods while appending/deleting table elements.